# Searching from different workbook and copying values

Tags: vb.net, vba, excel

I have 2 wb `to_update_example_1` and `purchasing_list`

basically what I am trying to do is to a loop row by row on workbook `to_update_example_1` if the same name is found to copy the a variable to the `purchasing_list` workbook.

However it keeps giving me error `91` at the searching portion and I would need an advice how do I write `vVal2`(which is the Qty) to Purchasing list workbook the column is just beside the found name so I tried to use active cell offset but didn't work too

any advice is appreciated thanks

```
Sub Macro1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Integer
Dim vVal1, vVal2 As String

Numrows = Range("A1", Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
Range("A1").Select  ' Select cell a2.
For x = 1 To Numrows ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times.
    vVal1 = Cells(x, 8)
    vVal2 = Cells(x, 7)

    Windows("Purchasing List.xls").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:=vVal1, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row

    ''write to Qty cell beside the found name ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) = vVal2
    Windows("To_update_example_1.xlsm").Activate

    ''''''''ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `Find` function, it's recommended if you set a `Range` object to the `Find` result, and also prepare your code for a scenario that `Find` didn't find `vVal1` in `"Purchasing List.xls"` workbook. You can achieve it by using the following line `If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then`.

**Note**: avoid using `Select`, `Activate` and `ActiveSheet`, instead fully qualify all your Objects - see in my code below (with comments).

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim x As Long, Numrows As Long
Dim vVal1 As String, vVal2 As String
Dim PurchaseWb As Workbook
Dim ToUpdateWb As Workbook
Dim FindRng As Range

' set workbook object of "Purchasing List" excel workbook
Set PurchaseWb = Workbooks("Purchasing List.xls")

' set workbook object of "To_update_example_1" excel workbook
Set ToUpdateWb = Workbooks("To_update_example_1.xlsm")

With ToUpdateWb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' <-- I think you are trying to loop on "To_update_example_1.xlsm" file , '<-- change "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    ' Set numrows = number of rows of data.
    Numrows = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    For x = 1 To Numrows ' Establish "For" loop to loop "numrows" number of times
        vVal1 = .Cells(x, 8)
        vVal2 = .Cells(x, 7)

        ' change "Sheet2" to your sheet's name in "Purchasing List.xls" file where you are looking for vVal1
        Set FindRng = PurchaseWb.Sheets("Sheet2").Cells.Find(What:=vVal1, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns)
        If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then '<-- make sure Find was successful finding vVal1
            ' write to Qty cell beside the found name ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) = vVal2
            ' Not sure eactly what you want to do now ???

        Else ' raise some kind of notification
            MsgBox "Unable to find " & vVal1, vbInformation
        End If
    Next x
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the help! it worked great! you are great! there is however just 1 more portion if  you could assist me with. when the name is found i would actually need to copy the Qty(which i had saved into variable vVal2 which is actually column G of its respective X row of to_update_example_1.xslm to column F of Purchasing List i tired to do an  ActiveCell.Offset(0, -2) = vVal2 after the IF statement and after a hecka long wait with a few not found it didn't work(sadly) any thoughts on how 1) it could be sped up and 2) how do i copy it the required quantity over? thanks in advance!

Comment: @JonathanLim can you share a screen-shot with a sample of data in your post ? it will help me understand better what you are rying to do

Comment: humm..  am new to this.. how do i attach the screenshot or the file.. i'm ok to attach the file except i can't seem to find where to do it from..

Comment: any possibility for me to facebook you or something? i tried to go to ur profile to msg or attach you but... still didn't manage to find it

Comment: i found it!
[Purchasing list](https://ibb.co/hrzGPx) this is the screenshot of the purchasing list
[to_update](https://ibb.co/kog7Wc) this is the screenshot of to_update list essentially to_update is a excel that is downloaded from an our online store and purchasing list is our offline list, we need to update our purchasing list to do stock accounting purchasing etc. so this purchasing list has quite abit of skus in 1 sheet column H is unique so i tot if i could do a macro to compare column H of to_update to column H of purchasing list and copy the Qty over it will save me abit of time

Answer (score 1):

**Edited** to account for OP's comment about where to search and write values

ShaiRado already told you where the flaw was

here's an alternative code

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim cell As Range, FindRng As Range

    Dim purchListSht As Worksheet
    Set purchListSht = Workbooks("Purchasing List.xls").Worksheets("purchaseData") '(change "purchaseData" to your actual "purchase" sheet name)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    With Workbooks("to_update_example_1").Sheets("SourceData") ' reference your "source" worksheet in "source" workbook (change "SourceData" to your actual "source" sheet name)
        For Each cell In .Range("H1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) ' loop through referenced "source" sheet column "H" not empty cells
            Set FindRng = purchListSht.Columns("G").Find(What:=cell.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns) ' try finding current cell content in "purchase" sheet column "G"
            If Not FindRng Is Nothing Then FindRng.Offset(, -2).Value = cell.Offset(, -1).Value ' if successful, write the value of the cell one column left of the current cell to the cell two columns to the left of found cell
        Next
    End With
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @JonathanLim, any feddback?

Comment: wow that works exactly as i required it.. its just amazing... i spent nights after night on it and all it took was 2 hrs on stackoverflow..any idea if the workbook name for the Workbooks("to_update_example_1") has to be fixed? as when we download the info from our online shop the filename is actually dynamic although the sheet name is always constant

Comment: you may then want to mark @ShaiRado 's answer as accepted. Since that was the answer solving your core issue

Comment: if i have further question do i addon here or create another post? as i currently have 2 other question. 1) the filename is dynamic would i have to always come to the backend to copy the file name and 2) if item not found how do i write on the to_update_example_1 file probably on column N of the corresponding row "item not updated" or somehting like that

Comment: 1st, you should accept Shai Rado's answer. 2nd, post a new question for new issues

Comment: @DisplayName as always nice "short" answer, code style still looks familiar with another user here in the past ;)

Comment: @ShaiRado, it's your second time at it: I must start believing it!

Comment: @JonathanLim you haven't still accepted ShaiRado's solution!